# How to tell Sonar to analyze *.ts files instead of *.js files

Tags: javascript, typescript, sonarqube, istanbul

In my project there is sonar scanner which is analyzing only *.js files (probably there is such configuration or so on). Also I have istanbul code coverage which generates a perfect lcov file with the results.

This lcov file has references to *.ts files which are not analyzed by Sonar. So the question is how to tell Sonar to analyze *.ts files instead of *.js files?

Now i'm getting somthing like this -

```
Could not resolve 10 file paths in [coverage.lcov], first unresolved path: 
[path]/test.ts .
```

I would really appreciate any help and it will be super if someone can share their working configuration file `sonar-project.properties`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't configured in *sonar-project.properties* but through the GUI: **Administration > General Settings > SonarJS > File Suffixes**

Comment: I configured like above, but I am getting the error, 
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Language of file 'src/app/Mvr/mvr.****.****.ts' can not be decided as the file matches patterns of both sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx and sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue,**/*.ts
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Set build name.
and sonarqube scanner failed.
I am using sonarqube 5.6

could you help me on this.